# How does matplotlibs quiver work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to understand Quiver by trial and error but my math is not so on point. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this.

I have a histogram as a matrix like this:

```
magnitude, angle = [[3,2,4,3,9], [x,x,x,x,x]]
```

Angle is not yet determined but on the histogram the Angle are the bins and the magnitude is the Y. The first bin would represent the first 1/5 of the circle and thus the Angle there.

The problem however why i've not yet filled the angle is because I want to draw 5 lines/vectors from one point with plt.quiver.

```
plt.quiver(x,y,u,v)
```

X and Y speaks for itself but I cannot figure out where u and v stands for. The documentation doesn't say much either. I need to draw 5 lines from the same point with a certain angle and magnitude which is given in the histogram but I cannot get it to work. Am i even using the function the right way? Thanks !!

btw I'm making a hog(histogram of gradients) and the result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The call signature of quiver is [`quiver(X, Y, U, V)`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html).
It often helps to reduce the problem to a minimal example. Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax=plt.subplots()

ax.quiver([0,1.5],[.5,1.5],[1,-0.5],[1,-1],
          angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.)

ax.set_xlim([-1,2])
ax.set_ylim([0,2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

This code adds two arrows. The first starts at point `(x=0, y=0.5)`, the second starts at `(1.5, 1.5)`. The first arraw goes in direction `(u=1,v=1)`, the second in direction (-0.5,-1).

Now in this case we set `scale_units='xy'` and `scale=1` such that `u` and `v` are in data coordinates and the arrow's endpoint is `(x0+u0, y0+v0)`. In case we chose the scale units differently, the length of the arrow would be different, but the direction would be the same.

So if you call `quiver(X, Y, U, V)`, you plot `len(U)` different arrows; the `i`th arrow starting at `X[i], Y[i]`, and pointing in direction `U[i],Y[i]`.

This means that in order to plot 5 arrows per position, you might call  `quiver` five times, with the same grid arguments `X` and `Y` but with differing `U` and `V`.

Comment: Alright, and what if my data only contains magnitude and angles? Because I have a histogram with 9 bins. Every bin represents 1/9 of an angle and the   whatever is in the bins a.k.a. how much is representing the magnitude.

Comment: Right now I've got this. http://imgur.com/a/Ts1x5. I dont understand why the line doesnt stop at 3.3. NVM I GOT IT. It was the scale

Comment: Because you set the scale to 0.1. So the line will stop at (32, 32).

Comment: got it. I've got one more question. Thanks first and foremost for your help. I was already experimetning beforehand but I was not using for example the right scale neither was I using scale_units='xy' which also puts everything in perspective now. However I'm using the magnitude * np.sin(angle) equation to solve because I just have a angle and magnitude. By experimenting I can  see that I can make the vector go round by changing the angle from 0 to 6. When the angle is 0, the arrows points to the right. Do you know what scale this angle is using in this formula?

Comment: The angle that `numpy.sin` is taking is in radiants. One circle is 2*np.pi. So if you have the angle in degrees, you get the angle in radiants by dividing by 180 and multipliying by pi. `np.sin(angle_in_deg /180.*np.pi)`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) documentation

> Call signatures

```
quiver(U, V, **kw)
quiver(U, V, C, **kw)
quiver(X, Y, U, V, **kw)
quiver(X, Y, U, V, C, **kw)
```

> Parameters
>   `X` : The x coordinates of the arrow locations
>   `Y` : The y coordinates of the arrow locations
>   `U` : The x components of the arrow vectors
>   `V` : The y components of the arrow vectors

So essentially `(x, y)` denotes the *location* of each quiver, and `(u, v)` denote the *orientation of the vector*.

Comment: Alright, that means I should use this for the u and v right. Thanks btw! Didnt read correctly I suppose.u = x1 + 14 * np.cos(70)
v = y1 + 14 * np.sin(70). I saw that you can make a whole circle by changing the number 70 I have from 0 to about 7. What scale for angles should I use?